# Does IotHub>EventHub>FA store the sequence of the message sent

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

Here is the scenario:

Device1 sends two iothub D2C Messages at one time:

1. That sets the flag to true
2. That sets the flag to false

The Iot Messge Routing routs the message to eventhub which will trigger the EventHubTriggered Function App:
In this case, is it guaranteed that the flag value will be false as the 2 was sent after 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub guarantees that messages are sent in order for **that unique device**. It does not guarantee ordering between devices:

*example* : **device a** sends `[a1,a2,a3]` and then **device b** sends `[b1,b2,b3]` . IoT Hub will guarantee that `a3` is always received after `a1` and `a2`, though it can happen that `[b1,b2,b3]` are all received before `[a1,a2,a3]`.

> The Iot Messge Routing routs the message to eventhub which will trigger the EventHubTriggered Function App: In this case, is it guaranteed that the flag value will be false as the 2 was sent after 1?

Yes! Because this is sent by the same device and IoT Hub only expects one connection per device.